# Generating binary lists that sum to a given number

Tags: python

I am attempting Project Euler #15, which essentially reduces to computing the number of binary lists of length *2*size* such that their entries sum to *size*, for the particular case *size = 20*. For example, if *size = 2* there are 6 such lists: [1,1,0,0], [1,0,1,0], [1,0,0,1], [0,1,1,0], [0,1,1,0], [0,1,0,1], [0,0,1,1]. Of course the number of such sequences is trivial to compute for any value *size* and is equal to some binomial coefficient but I am interested in explicitly generating the correct sequences in Python. I have tried the following:

```
import itertools

size = 20

binary_lists = itertools.product(range(2), repeat = 2*size)

lattice_paths = {lists for lists in binary_lists if sum(lists) == size}
```

but the last line makes me run into memory errors. What would be a neat way to accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as asking "how many ways can I place *size* 1's in *2\*size* slots?"

Comment: @NightShadeQueen: Not if you want to see all of those ways listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are far too many for the case of size=20 to iterate over (even if we don't materialize them, 137846528820 is not a number we can loop over in a reasonable time), so it's not particularly useful.

But you can still do it using built-in tools by thinking of the *positions* of the 1s:

```
from itertools import combinations

def bsum(size):
    for locs in combinations(range(2*size), size):
        vec = [0]*(2*size)
        for loc in locs:
            vec[loc] = 1
        yield vec
```

which gives

```
>>> list(bsum(1))
[[1, 0], [0, 1]]
>>> list(bsum(2))
[[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1]]
>>> sum(1 for x in bsum(12))
2704156
>>> factorial(24)//factorial(12)**2
2704156
```

Comment: Although for *size* = 20 this seems to be taking a very long time to compute... Way more than the "1-minute rule" they have over at Project Euler. I can't really think of a neater solution, however.

Comment: I don't understand.  In the very first sentence of this answer, I remind you that there are way too many to iterate over.  This is not how you're intended to solve Euler #15.  For that, you should either (1) use the combinatorial formula, or (2) use dynamic programming.  Many Euler problems have a brute force solution which takes forever, and might even work in the example, but will fail on the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of the math on this problem, but your last line is taking a generator and dumping it into a list, and based on your example, and your size of 20, that is a massive list. If you want to sum it, just iterate, but I don't think you can get a nice view of every combo